# How do I make a regular expression with character classes and repeating patterns or groups?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a regular expression that would accept any of these examples:

```
|x-x-x-x-|x-x-x-x-|x-x-x-x-|x-x-x-x-|
|x-------|--------|x-------|--------|
|--------|x-------|--------|x-------|
|-xx---x-|-xxxx-x-|--------|ooooooo-|
|xo--oo--|--------|xo------|--------|
|--------|x-------|--------|x-------|
```

So far this is what I have:

```
\|([\-|x|o]{9}\|){4}
```

I wouldn't like to make a group out of "x-x-x-x-|" as well, but may be of every "(-|x|o)". If you notice there's just 8 characters within "|...|" should I change to 8 repetitions? on [regex](http://regexper.com/#%5C%7C(%5B%5C-%7Cx%7Co%5D%7B9%7D%5C%7C)%7B4%7D) site show that it'll repeat 8 times.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The problem with "I would like a regex that matches ..." is that a possible correct answer is always `.*`. Would you like to *reject* anything?

Comment: @GregHewgill Best comment I've seen on regex. Why don't more people do that? All the questions I've seen I'm the only person who asks, what do you not want to match? Faith in humanity restored...

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick reply. I'd like to reject anything that between '|' isn't '-', 'x' or 'o', and has the sum total of these characters be anything different than 8, and this pattern repeats 4 times completing the line.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to separate items in your character class with `|`. You're just including `|` twice in the class. And `-` only signifies a range when it's separating pairs, so you don't need to escape it with \ when it's in first position.

Answer (score 1):

From your description:

> I'd like to reject anything that between '|' isn't '-', 'x' or 'o', and has the sum total of these characters be anything different than 8, and this pattern repeats 4 times completing the line.

the following regex might be what you are looking for:

```
\|([-xo]{8}\|){4}
```

Broken down, this is:

- `[-xo]` - a character class that matches one of `-`, `x`, or `o`
- `[-xo]{8}` - exactly 8 characters matching the character class
- `[-xo]{8}\|` - 8 characters followed by a `|`
- `([-xo]{8}\|){4}` - 8 characters followed by a `|`, exactly four times

Finally, a `\|` at the start matches the initial `|`. You may need to add anchors (`^` and/or `$`) to the start and end of your regex, depending on how you are using it.

Comment: In the comments to the Q the OP says 'completing the line', which I think vaguely implies `^` and `$`.

Comment: @KingMob: That's right, but some regex functions automatically anchor the beginning and/or the end of the expression. For example, Java's `Pattern.matches()` automatically anchors at both ends.

Comment: Oh, sure, just trying to second-guess the OP and mentioning for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

```
\|(([-x]-){4}\|){4}
```

You can see it in action here: http://refiddle.co/2ecn